# Finding highest number in text file

Tags: algorithm, file, text, max

I have a text file that contains 50 student names and scores for each student in the format.

```
               foreName.Surname:Mark
```

I have figured out how to split up each line into a forename, surname and mark using this code.

```
            string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"StudentExamMarks.txt");


        int i = 0;
        var items = from line in Lines
                    where i++ != 0
                    let words = line.Split(' ', '.', ':')
                    select new
                    {
                        foreName = words[0],
                        Surname = words[1],
                        Mark = words[2]

                    };
```

I am unsure of how i would incorporate a findMax algorithm into to find the highest mark and display the pupil with the highest mark. this as i have not used text files that often.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any sorting algorithm there is a [Pseudo Code](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mitra/csFall2015/cs303/lectures/basic_algo.html)  available to find maximum number in any list or array..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, required just parse all files.

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"StudentExamMarks.txt");

    string maxForeName = null;
    string maxSurName = null;
    var maxMark = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        var tmp = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (tmp.Length == 3)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(tmp[2]);
            if (i == 0 || value > maxMark)
            {
                maxMark = value;
                maxForeName = tmp[0];
                maxSurName = tmp[1];
            }
        }
    }
```